# Where no funciona en laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

estoy usando query builder para hacer una consulta, el objetivo es obtener los usuarios de una tabla "A" que no estén en la tabla "B". La tabla B se enlaza con la tabla A atraves de su columna "propietario" que enlaza con la columna "id_usuario" de la tabla A.

Codigo:

```
     $usuarios_condominios = DB::table("usuarioscondominios")->join("users","usuarioscondominios.id_usuario","users.id")->where("usuarioscondominios.id_usuario","<>","propietarios_unidades.propietario")->get();
```

Tabla A:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla B:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado deberia ser el usuario con id 3 ya que es el unico que no esta en la tabla "A":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna idea de porque no funciona la consulta ?

Comment: ¿Sí te das cuenta de que haces un join entre dos tablas? ¿De donde es que sacas la tercera tabla propietarios_unidades? Por eso no funciona

Comment: WHERE funciona en Laravel perfectamente. Pero tú estás haciendo un JOIN poniendo como condición que los campos que relacionan las tablas no coincidan. Entonces, como es un JOIN, no te devuelve nada. Tienes que emplear una subconsulta, es decir, seleccionar de la tabla A aquellos registros cuyo id_usuario no está en (seleccionar de la tabla B el campo propietario).

Comment: Hola Jose me podrias mostrar un ejemplo ? recien estoy aprendiendo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes usar `rightJoin()` y luego un `whereNull()` para ver que usuario no esta en la tabla `propietarios_unidades`

```
$usuarios_condominios = DB::table("propietarios_unidades")
            ->rightJoin('users','propietarios_unidades.propietario','users.id')
            ->whereNull('propietarios_unidades.propietario')
            ->get();
        return $usuarios_condominios;
```